# How to display the selected drop-down option in Teams using adaptive cards

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using an adaptive card to prompt the drop-down list to the user. Once submit action is performed I want the selected user option to be displayed to the user in Teams. I am using a bot framework.

I probably want to display the userinput id which captures the data.

```
"items": [{ 
         "type": "Input.ChoiceSet", 
         "style": "compact",
         "id": "UserInput", 
          "choices" : categories  
          },
          {
         "type": "ActionSet",
         "actions": [{
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Confirm",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
        "type": "imBack",
        "value": ?????
    }
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please refer the below sample -https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-type-ahead-search-adaptive-cards/csharp

Are you trying the same?